# Interactive Grid popup-lov

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

IG - LOV there is no search option for LOVs that depend on other fields

There is no search option on IG LOV if the LOV depends on other fields. (LOV is composed dynamically)
Check the option if it can be solved.

You need to find a way to allow the user to filter the data based on what is in the child hunt
When there is a cascading LOV column in apex in ig that is a child, the search option is lost and the user cannot search using the data from that column.
The tribe needs to find a way to make it possible for him

I dont know how to  make it work